# C# SQL select date problems

Tags: c#, sql

I`m New in c#
I have problems with SQL and DATEs
in this query I have error...

> ERROR [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC dBase
>   Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria
>   expression.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char split = '.';
            string[] s = dateTimePicker1.Text.Split(split);
            string sx = s[0] + "." + s[1] + ".";


            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;
SourceDB=C:\sales\;Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
            oConn.Open();
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
            oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COD,PRICE,SMAN_COD FROM C:\sales\sl.DBF WHERE DATE='"+dateTimePicker1.Text+"'";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
            oConn.Close();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
```

Please Help Me

Comment: Is your "Date" column of type date? DateTime? What text does dateTimePicker1.Text contain (just a date value, or a date + a time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Parametrized Queries to Avoid Sql Injection](http://htc-hd2-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/cparametrized-queries-to-avoid-sql.html)

ooops, OdbcCommand seems different with SqlCommand For Parametriezed Queries.

Change

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COD,PRICE,SMAN_COD FROM C:\sales\sl.DBF WHERE DATE='"+dateTimePicker1.Text+"'";
```

To

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COD,PRICE,SMAN_COD FROM C:\sales\sl.DBF WHERE DATE=?";
oCmd.Parameters.Add ("DATE", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

Hopefully this will help you!

Comment: This worked... :) tnx.... But I need tur use dateTimePicker1.Text, becaues in this case I make only selects.. I must use base waht is

Answer (score 7):

Don't send the date/time value in the SQL at all. Use a parameterized query - that way you don't need to concern yourself with the format. Why complicate things and leave yourself open to subtle problems when you can communicate the data without parsing and formatting it?

Additionally, if you get in the habit of using parameters for all values, you'll avoid SQL injection attacks.

In this case you'd use `DateTimePicker.Value` instead of `DateTimePicker.Text`, to get at the value as a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that the date sent into the database is formated in a proper way, I would recommend the following date format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

This will, to my knowledge, work regardless of the culture of your machine, and the machine running the database server.

This format is called ISO 8601.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your Output Date is in the Format of 12/01/2011

If it is. you need to convert it to 2010-01-12

the DateTimePicker i think has a property called SelectedDate instead of Text

If that is the case then

use:

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DatePicker1.SelectedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because sql expects the date to be in a certain format. Try replacing

```
dateTimePicker1.Text
```

with

```
dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString("dd mmm yyyy");
```

Hope this helps.